# Get a value from a <i> tag with hooks in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to get a value from i tag with hook. When I click on it but in console, the result is undefined.
Here is my code snippet.

```
const deleteCar = event => {
    const car_id = event.target.value
    console.log(car_id)
}

<tbody>
        {
          props.cars && props.cars.map( car =>      
            (
            <tr key={car.id}>
                <td>{car.model}</td>              
                <td><i className="far fa-trash-alt" name="car_id" value={car.id} onClick={deleteCar}></i><i className="far fa-trash-alt"></i></td>
            </tr>         
              )      
            )}         
 </tbody>
```

How can I do that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it was an `input` tag for example you could access its value attribute through `event.target.value`, but that not the case for `icon` tag. Use the `getAttribute` method in order to access it:

```
const deleteCar = event => {
    const car_id = event.target.getAttribute('value')
    console.log(car_id)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that you are not passing the `event` in your function `onClick`. It should be: `onClick={(event) =>deleteCar(event) }`

Comment: It's giving me the same result

Comment: I would assume you want to pass the carId as parameter of the function. `onClick={deleteCar(car)}` and in `const deleteCar = car => {console.log(car)} `.

Comment: With the above code, I've an error in onClick. Car is not defined

Comment: Can you consol.log the value of the car? Something like `props.cars && props.cars.map((car)=>console.log(car))`?

Comment: I've updated my code. So, the car model is displayed

Comment: But the onClick function just returns undefined

Comment: When I do this :  const deleteCar = event => {console.log(event.target)}, I've : <i class="far fa-trash-alt" name="car_id" value="4"></i>

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in **two ways**. But both will need a `state` to hold the `car.id` for you. (**Reminder: since you are using `<i>` tag, you can't just put `value` as `prop`. That's for `<input>` tag only)

1. Using **React Hook** (`useEffect`) - **better option (proven to work every time)**:-

```js
const [carId, setCarId] = useState('')
const [isDelete, setIsDelete] = useState(false)

// handle delete of car
const deleteCar = () => {
    if(isDelete) {
      // perform delete
      console.log(carId)

      // reset states involve
      setCardId('')
      setIsDelete(false)
    }
}

// invoke delete function
useEffect(()= > {
  deleteCar()
}, [isDelete])

<tbody>
  {props.cars && props.cars.map( car => (
    <tr key={car.id}>
      <td>{car.model}</td>              
      <td>
        <i 
          className="far fa-trash-alt" 
          onClick={() => {
            setCarId(car.id)
            setIsDelete(true)
          }}
        >
        </i>
        <i className="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
      </td>
    </tr>         
  ))}         
</tbody>
```

2. Just use normal `onClick` function:-

```js
const [carId, setCarId] = useState('')

// handle delete of car
const deleteCar = () => {
  // perform delete
  console.log(carId)

  // reset states involve
  setCardId('')
}

<tbody>
  {props.cars && props.cars.map( car => (
    <tr key={car.id}>
      <td>{car.model}</td>              
      <td>
        <i 
          className="far fa-trash-alt" 
          onClick={() => {
            setCarId(car.id)
            deleteCar()
          }}
        >
        </i>
        <i className="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
      </td>
    </tr>         
  ))}         
</tbody>
```

Comment: thank your! Your first code code worked fine compared to the second. However, I prefer to choose Buzatto's because it's short.